# Getting Camera model information of an image using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, camera

I am working on python automation in which I have to collect the camera model (canon, Nikon etc.) information of an image. I searched a lot but I am getting only pixel resolution, size and other data of an image.
Is there any API or library in which we can find the camera related each and every information or a particular API which gives camera model information.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python [`exifread`](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py) library can be used to extract a lot of information from a JPG image, including the `Image Make` and `Image Model`, for example:

```
import exifread

with open(r"sample.jpg", 'rb') as f_jpg:
    tags = exifread.process_file(f_jpg, details=True)
    print tags['Image Make']
    print tags['Image Model']
```

This could display something like:

```
Panasonic
DMC-TZ20
```

Note, I have not tested this with the latest version. It can be installed using:

```
pip install exifread
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, its working fine...i ran same snippet but used exifread instead of EXIF.